# Sums of variable size chunks of a list where sizes are given by other list

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to make the following sum given two lists:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = [2,3,5]
```

The result should be the sum of the every `b` element of `a` like:

1. `b[0] = 2` so the first sum result should be: `sum(a[0:2])`
2. `b[1] = 3` so the second sum result should be: `sum(a[2:5])`
3. `b[2] = 5` so the third sum result should be: `sum(a[5:10])`

The printed result: `1,9,35`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of `np.bincount` with `weights`:

```
groups = np.repeat(np.arange(len(b)), b)

np.bincount(groups, weights=a)
```

Output:

```
array([ 1.,  9., 35.])
```

Answer (score 6):

NumPy has a tool to do slice based sum-reduction with [`np.add.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html?highlight=ufunc%20reduceat#numpy.ufunc.reduceat) -

```
In [46]: np.add.reduceat(a,np.cumsum(np.r_[0,b[:-1]]))                          
Out[46]: array([ 1,  9, 35])
```

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like this?

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [2, 3, 5]

def some_function(a, b): # couldnt come up with a name :D
    last_index = 0

    for i in b:
        print(sum(a[last_index:last_index + i]))
        last_index += i

some_function(a, b)
```

Comment: output is 1, 9, 35 btw

Answer (score 3):

Hard to compete with the `np.bincount` solution, but here's another nice way to approach it with `np.cumsum`:

```py
strides = [0] + np.cumsum(b).tolist()  # [0, 2, 5, 10]
stride_slices = zip(strides[:-1], strides[1:])  # [(0, 2), (2, 5), (5, 10)]
[sum(a[s[0]: s[1]]) for s in stride_slices]
# [1, 9, 35]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a list comprehension with `sum`:

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b=[2,3,5]
r = [sum(a[(k:=sum(b[:i])):k+j]) for i, j in enumerate(b)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 9, 35]
```